# HTML&CSS - Should I style footer element? What is better practise?

Tags: css, html, footer, styling

I am currently learning web design and I have watched a lot of tutorials and read a ton of articles. Some people say that `<footer>` element is used for writing easy understandable code and basically just wrap their footer with these tags without styling it. But others put their content in it and use it for styling. So I have these questions:

1. Should I style my `<footer>` tag, or create another `<div>` in it and apply style to it?
2. If yes, is there a big difference?
3. What most people do? What is better practice?

Comment: The `<footer>`-tag is for your footer like the `<header>` is for your header. Thats just a pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically footer tag is introduced to contain information such as the author of the document, copyright information, links to terms of use, privacy policy, etc.

But It's on you, what you want in the footer side of page.

There is no standard practices mentioned for footer or header tag

Answer (score 2):

You are free to style the `<footer>` tag or not

From my experience I would recommend to create one `<div>` inside the footer to wrap the content and style it

Both are fine it's all up to you.

For a better readability and an easy maintainability better use the second option